# Angular routes modules

Tags: angular, module, router

I try to develop the routes in angular 8 by using the different modules of auth/pages and app, in every components.html: auth/pages/app.html I put router-outler
but I have an error in console of navigateur like this :

```
compiler.js:2175 Uncaught Error: Type AuthComponent is part of the declarations of 2 modules:
AuthModule and PagesModule! Please consider moving AuthComponent to a higher module that 
imports AuthModule and PagesModule. You can also create a new NgModule that exports and 
includes AuthComponent then import that NgModule in AuthModule and PagesModule.
```

**auth.module.ts :**

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AuthComponent,
        LoginComponent,
        RegisterComponent,
        ForgotPasswordComponent,
        ResetPasswordComponent
    ],
    exports: [

    ],
    imports: [
        FormsModule,
        CommonModule,
        AUTH_ROUTES
    ]
})
export class AuthModule { }
```

**auth-routes.modules.ts**

```
const authRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: "login", component: LoginComponent, data: { title: "Login" }
    },
    {
        path: "register", component: RegisterComponent, data: { title: "Register" }
    },
    {
        path: "forgot/password", component: ForgotPasswordComponent, data: { title: "Forgot Password" }
    },
    {
        path: "reset/password", component: ResetPasswordComponent, data: { title: "Reset Password" }
    }
];
export const AUTH_ROUTES = RouterModule.forChild(authRoutes);
```

**pages.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AuthComponent,
        AllUsersComponent,
        AllUsersComponent,
        TestrouteComponent,
        PagesComponent
    ],
    exports: [

    ],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        PAGES_ROUTES,
        AuthModule,
        CommonModule,
        RouterModule
    ]
})
```

**pages.routes.ts**

```
const pagesRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: "users", component: AllUsersComponent, data: { title: "Users" }
    },
    {
        path: "orders", component: AllOrdersComponent, data: { title: "Orders" }
    },
    {
        path: "protect", component: TestrouteComponent, data: { title: "Protect" }, canActivate: [AuthGuard]
    },
    {
        path: '', component: AuthComponent, loadChildren: '../pages/auth/auth.module.ts#AuthModule'
    },
];
export const PAGES_ROUTES = RouterModule.forChild(pagesRoutes);
```

**app.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    PagesComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    PagesModule,
    ServiceModule
  ],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: JwtInterceptor,
      multi: true
    },
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: ErrorInterceptor,
      multi: true
    }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '', component: PagesComponent, loadChildren: '../app/pages/pages.module.ts#PagesModule'
  },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `AuthComponent` from your declarations array in the pages.module.ts file.
You will also need to export the `AuthComponent` in auth.module.ts and then you should be able to use it no problem in your pages.routes.ts file.

Comment: Now I have an other error:  Error: Component AllOrdersComponent is not part of any NgModule or the module has not been imported into your module.

Comment: Right you'll need to declare the AllOrdersComponent in your pages.module.ts file. Looks like there was a bad copy/paste and you have declared AllUsersComponent twice in your pages module.